# create and write two CSV simultaneously golang

Tags: csv, go

I am trying to create two CSV files and write both simultaneously. This code doesn't work that way, but it's just to exemplify what I want to do. Since (* csv.Writer) is a pointer I don't know how I can differentiate it from another file. Is it possible to do that?

```
package test

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var csvSuccess *os.File
var csvError *os.File
var csvErr error
var csvWriterSuccess *csv.Writer
var csvWriterError *csv.Writer
var mutex *sync.Mutex

func init() {
    csvSuccess, csvErr = os.Create("sucess-result.csv")
    csvError, csvErr = os.Create("error-result.csv")
    if csvErr != nil {
        panic("Error open file")
    }
    csvWriterSuccess = csv.NewWriter(csvSuccess)
    csvWriterError = csv.NewWriter(csvSuccess)
    mutex = &sync.Mutex{}
}

func WriteRecordSuccess(record []string) {
    mutex.Lock()
    if err := csvWriterSuccess.Write(record); err != nil {
        if err != nil {
            panic("Error writing success record")
        }
        csvWriterSuccess.Flush()
    }
    mutex.Unlock()
}

func WriteRecordError(record []string) {
    mutex.Lock()
    if err := csvWriterError.Write(record); err != nil {
        if err != nil {
            panic("Error writing error record")
        }
        csvWriterError.Flush()
    }
    mutex.Unlock()
}

func ClosecsvFile() {
    csvWriterSuccess.Flush()
    csvWriterError.Flush()
    csvSuccess.Sync()
    csvError.Sync()
    csvSuccess.Close()
    csvError.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `init` function you have both writers writing to the success file.

```
csvWriterSuccess = csv.NewWriter(csvSuccess)
csvWriterError = csv.NewWriter(csvSuccess)
```

Write to the success and error files separately.

```
csvWriterSuccess = csv.NewWriter(csvSuccess)
csvWriterError = csv.NewWriter(csvError)
```